# How to change view on the right view with SplitViewNavigator Flex 4.6

Tags: apache-flex, split, view, navigator

I am creating a mobile app with Flex 4.6 and I'm using the SplitViewNavigator with tabbed application. I have one left view that never changes that has a static list associated with it. I have multiple views for the right panel of the `SplitViewNavigator`. I can load the left view and the 1st right view but do not know how to change the view of the right view after a selection has been made from the list in the left view.

My main app file has the following code to load the split view and display the left and 1st right view.

```
<s:SplitViewNavigator id="svn" width="100%" height="100%">
    <s:ViewNavigator id="leftNav" width="30%" height="100%" firstView="views.LeftView"/>
    <s:ViewNavigator id="rightNav" width="70%" height="100%" firstView="views.RightView1"/>
</s:SplitViewNavigator>
```

My left view just has a simple list and I can determine which item has been selected but I don't know how to make the right view change. Assume the right views are just called RightView1, RightView2, etc.

I am assuming I need to use a `pushView` method but do not know how to reference the right view id (rightNav) in the main app file from the leftView view. But I could be way off here so any help would be greatly appreciated.

cheers,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to do something like this:

**Main.mxml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:TabbedViewNavigatorApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                                  xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
                                  applicationDPI="160"
                                  creationComplete="this_creationCompleteHandler(event)"
                                  >
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import events.ViewEvent;

            import mx.events.FlexEvent;

            import views.RightView1;

            protected function this_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
            {
                leftNav.addEventListener(ViewEvent.CHANGE_VIEW, leftNav_changeViewHandler);
            }

            protected function leftNav_changeViewHandler(event:ViewEvent):void
            {
                rightNav.pushView(event.view);
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:SplitViewNavigator id="svn" width="100%" height="100%">
        <s:ViewNavigator id="leftNav" width="30%" height="100%" firstView="views.LeftView"  />
        <s:ViewNavigator id="rightNav" width="70%" height="100%" firstView="views.RightView1"/>
    </s:SplitViewNavigator>
</s:TabbedViewNavigatorApplication>
```

**LeftView.mxml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
        title="LeftView">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import events.ViewEvent;

            import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;

            import spark.events.IndexChangeEvent;

            private function labelFunc(item:Object):String
            {
                return getQualifiedClassName(item).split("::")[1];
            }

            protected function list_changeHandler(event:IndexChangeEvent):void
            {
                dispatchEvent(new ViewEvent(ViewEvent.CHANGE_VIEW, list.selectedItem as Class, true));
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <s:List id="list" height="100%" width="100%"
            dataProvider="{new ArrayCollection([RightView1, RightView2, RightView3])}"
            labelFunction="labelFunc"
            change="list_changeHandler(event)">

    </s:List>
</s:View>
```

**ViewEvent.as**:

```
package events
{
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class ViewEvent extends Event
    {

        public static const CHANGE_VIEW:String = "changeView";

        public function ViewEvent(type:String, view:Class, bubbles:Boolean=false, cancelable:Boolean=false)
        {
            super(type, bubbles, cancelable);

            this.view = view;
        }

        public var view:Class;

        override public function clone():Event
        {
            return new ViewEvent(type, view, bubbles, cancelable);
        }
    }
}
```

This worked for me, but I don't like `this_creationCompleteHandler` part in `Main.mxml` and it's up to you how to catch `ViewEvent`. Hope this can help.

Comment: Thank Art that worked.  I made some minor changes to match my exact scenario.  Seems like a lot of code just to change a view.  Is it just me or does Adobe make things overly complicated.

cheers,

Comment: @user1332657 Well, maybe there are simplier ways to achieve this. At least you can use LeftView instead of leftNav ViewNavigator (or even list itself) and catch list change event directly in Main class. It will reduce code, but increase associations between classes.

Comment: Thanks Art I did consider putting my Left view in my main class but I like to keep all views seperate for debugging purposes and clutter.  Your scenario worked perfectly for me and I really appreciate it.  I was just commenting that something that is so fundamental to any app is so complicated to do.

Comment: Thanx Art! Good method Another example on this page (at the end of the article) :
http://devgirl.org/2011/12/01/flex-mobile-development-splitviewnavigator-tutorial/ A complete application to download : http://devgirl.org/files/RIAUnleashed/